# What is the little padlock symbol near every Visual Studio tab?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

Sometimes on the right side of any Visual Studio tab there will be a little padlock symbol. What is it?

I thought it was something like source-control, but my solution is not checked in source-control.

EDIT: Thank you for your answers so far, BUT I can edit the files.
When I am in debug mode it has also this padlock sign, but when I am holding my mouse over the tab I can read "Read-Only".
Not in debug-mode (normal edit mode, nothing running), there is also the padlock symbol. But when I hold my mouse over the tab there is no readonly text.

Is there an other definition of the padlock sign? Or how can I see the padlock sign while editing my normal source code (and no debugging running)?

Comment: Yeah, "read-only" doesn't mean "can't edit".  For example, files that are read-only from being in source control show up with the lock until you try to edit the file, and then the file will be checked-out and the lock will disappear.  Similarly, even read-only files are editable in memory, and the lock will disappear when you save.  There's actually an option to disallow editing of read-only files on disk, but it's off by default.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have x64, and can not edit in memory. I always have to hit build solution (although I have checked the build checkboxed in solution configuration). Could this be also the reason for the padlock symbols?

Comment: x64 disallows Edit and Continue, not editing in memory. Editing in memory just means the changes haven't been saved to disk.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It indicates that the file is read-only.

Comment: chrs @dthorpe - would you also know what the padlock which appears next to some variables in intellisense means?

Answer (score 21):

If you're using version control (in my case - git) paddlock also indicates that the file is "locked" for a commit.

After any change in the file it changes to red tickmark. Then if you commit changes to this file it switches back to paddlock.

Answer (score 13):

Click the "stop debugging" red box button. That's why it's not letting you edit. Just found out myself ;)

Comment: I think that can, indeed be one of the reasons, in addition to the other answers.

Comment: FYI - Actually, I had stopped debugging, but still had the lock icons on only one of my source files.  I couldn't type in that source file at all, but could in the others, even though all were part of the project.  Finally, I started the app as a debug run and closed the app then I could edit the file again. Terrible Visual Studio, just terrible.

Answer (score 2):

That means that the file is not editable by Visual Studio; usually it comes up when you ask VS to navigate to a definition that exists only in metadata. It will display what data it can, but show a padlock to indicate that you can't edit it.

Answer (score 2):

Starting the debugger and stopping it cleared them for me...

Answer (score 0):

If your case is something like this picture:

[image: Solution exploere]

As far as I know, it indicates that changes are pushed to your version control repo.
In other words, your version control repo is not ahead of what you have on your local machine. In the case of changes that are not committed and pushed, there would be a red check mark next to your files.