# VS - Accidentally clicked publish button on bottom bar, can't undo

Tags: visual-studio-2015

So I accidentally clicked the "Publish" button on bottom right of the bottom blue bar, and now all my files in solution have this weird blue lock icon. I don't know how to remove and haven't tried anything or found anything on how to undo this.

[Blue lock icons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7BEF.png)

[Bottom bar changed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6qmAu.png)

Comment: It is read only I think this question answers what you have going on... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3242279/what-is-that-little-padlock-symbol-right-near-every-visual-studio-tab

Comment: But is there a way to remove this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As they mentioned [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/lock-unlock-folders-files)

> A folder or file can be locked or unlocked to deny or restore the user's privileges. Privileges include checking out an item for edit into a different workspace or checking in Pending Changes to an item from a different workspace.

**To lock a folder or file from Source Control Explorer**

1. On the View *menu, choose *Other Windows,and then choose Source Control Explorer. You can also double-click Source Control in Team Explorer.
2. In Source Control Explorer, in a workspace, open the shortcut menu for the folder or file to which you want to apply a lock, and then choose Lock.
3. In the *Lock *dialog box select the file or folder you want.
4. Choose either the Check Out lock or the Check In lock type, and then choose Lock.

And **To unlock a folder or file from Source Control Explorer**

1. On the View *menu, choose *Other Windows,and then choose Source Control Explorer.
2. In Source Control Explorer, open the shortcut menu for the folder or file from which you want to remove a lock, and then choose Unlock.

Credits for this answer is [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/lock-unlock-folders-files), so for more information your can check that url from official **MSDN Documentation**.