# Form Designer showing blank tab when opening form

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-forms-designer

I have one particular form which is not being rendered in the form designer. I just get a blank screen:

[image]

The code builds and runs successfully. The form works fine at runtime.

I've checked and re-checked the `csproj` file. Everything is fine. `InitializeComponent` is called in the form's constructor.

I just upgraded to Visual Studio 2019 (16.11.5) and I also tried opening the form in the latest preview of Visual Studio 2022. Nothing is working.

Any ideas on how I can fix this problem?

Comment: @JohnG The tab page is from VS (as per screenshot). The form has a multitude of controls spread across different panels.

Comment: There is no tab control on the form. Yes. the controls are all added in the designer. The designer however is now showing blank (see screenshot). Not even an empty form.

Comment: Note the padlock icon in the tab header, the IDE knows that the designer can't work.  The canonical [is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3242279/what-is-the-little-padlock-symbol-near-every-visual-studio-tab/37226569)

Comment: @HansPassant Other forms are checked in and can be viewed in the designer just the same.

Comment: Make a new form, close the designer, copypasta the contents of just the broken form's class in Designer.cs into the new form's class in Designer.cs (everything inside the `class { ... }` not including the class.. and then comment out anything that references code in the main form codebehind (like event handlers)). When you've got no more wiggly lines save it and open the new form visual Designer again - blank or working?

Comment: @CaiusJard Also blank

Comment: I would then start removing stuff (maybe delete an innermost panel and everything control that goes with it, then all the initcomponent code that relates to those now-gone controls) from your new, blank form (because you don't mind wrecking it) and see at what point does it come alive again, see if you can narrow down the thing causing the problem. I propose removal first because then the compiler can help you with "member not found" style errors... I'd also make sure to fully close all code and designer windows after each change, and reopen the faulty one.

Comment: Hopefully you don't get all the way back to an empty class with no controls, that is still crashing!

Comment: Finally solved it. I had to go all the way back to an empty form and rebuild it till I found the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with VS 2022. What worked for me was to create a new VB application forms (.NET framework). The dessigner pane worked OK there, then close it and re open my c# forms app and then it worked. ¯_(ツ)_/

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: I'm pretty new with c# winforms.

I had the same issue with the designer showing blank.
After lots of screwing around, I found that "**Resize**" "**FormClosing**" and "**OnLoad**" events where being called/used in partial forms that where inherited.

Example: baseform.cs -> formMenu.cs -> dashboard.cs

```
public partial class baseform: form {}
public partial class formMenu : baseform {}
public partial class dashboard : formMenu {}
```

"**Resize**" "**FormClosing**" and "**OnLoad**" where set / called in the baseform,
this blanks out the designer of the forms that come after.
When removing these 3 events and using them in the last class "dashboard", everything works fine again.